# Should I pass a large array by reference or value?

Tags: performance, pass-by-reference, rust, pass-by-value

I am building a Game Boy emulator in Rust.  I created a readByteFromMemory() function which takes as a parameter an 8KB array which represents the Game Boy's internal memory which was 8KB.  I am thinking of two options here:

```
fn readByteFromMemory(internalRAM: [u8;0x2000]) -> u8
```

or

```
fn readByteFromMemory(internalRAM: &[u8;0x2000]) -> u8
```

The only thing I could find that references this topic is this article: http://words.steveklabnik.com/pointers-in-rust-a-guide which states:

```
But don’t reach for that pointer until you must! Make sure that the 
struct is large enough by performing some tests before you add in the 
complexity of pointers.
```

I ran a benchmark test on both options and it seems that no matter if the optimizer turned on or off, the pass by pointer one was much faster (as expected).

Though interestingly enough the pass by value was slightly faster if the optimizer was turned off as shown here:

```
➜  rustTest$  rustc --test -O passByTest.rs
➜  rustTest$  ./passByTest --bench         

running 2 tests
test ptrBench   ... bench:         1 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test valueBench ... bench:       221 ns/iter (+/- 2)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 2 measured

➜  rustTest$  rustc --test  passByTest.rs 
➜  rustTest$  ./passByTest --bench       

running 2 tests
test ptrBench   ... bench:        13 ns/iter (+/- 3)
test valueBench ... bench:       152 ns/iter (+/- 1)
```

My question is: what seems to be the threshold in bytes where passing by reference makes sense over passing by value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't answer your question directly because, as with so many other things, it depends on where the code is, what the code around it is doing, what the access patterns are, blah, blah, blah.  If you're concerned about performance, *you have to profile*.

That said...

- "Large" values passed by value in Rust are *actually* passed by reference as an optimisation.  By "large", I believe it's anything larger than a few pointers.  Again, this is an optimisation, so you're relying on the compiler to make a reasonable choice here.  In most cases, it should choose correctly.

  Also keep in mind that you can't "pass logically by value, actually by reference" (which is what the compiler is doing) yourself; that would imply using `&move` reference, which doesn't exist in the language yet.

  I believe Steve's comment there should be interpreted a little more liberally as: "don't override the compiler yourself *unless* profiling tells you to."
- So is there any difference between the two?  Yes!  If you pass a `[u8; 0x2000]`, then the caller has to make a *copy* of the value before it passes it, assuming you want to be able to use it again later on.  That's likely where the performance difference is coming from.

  Note that the compiler *won't* make a copy if you are moving the value into the function.  This includes all non-copyable types (like `Box`, `String` and `Vec`), and *should* include copyable types that the compiler knows you aren't going to use again.

The appropriate choice is `&[u8; 0x2000]` because:

- You only need to *read* from the value (*i.e.* if you wanted to modify it, you'd need a `&mut [u8; 0x2000]`.
- You don't want to take ownership of the value (in which case, you'd pass by value).

Again, to re-emphasize: don't start playing games with "this is a big value therefore I will use pass-by-reference" because the compiler is *already* doing this, and you it's really hard to get it right manually.

Comment: Regarding the second point: Yes, in theory the compiler should be able to act "as if it was moved" when the copyable value isn't used after the function call. However, like other optimizations, this depends on LLVM being aware that it's legal, and I'm not sure whether rustc currently communicates this properly (I think there was an issue with `llvm.lifetime.end` being placed too conservatively).

Comment: I would also like add that appropriate choice is probably even `&[u8]` and not `&[u8; 0x2000]`.

Comment: But shouldn't the compiler know that since it is being passed immutably, that the array should be "passed logically by value, actually by reference"?  It seems that a full copy isn't necessary here, unless I am missing something.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev  Why would &[u8] be more appropriate?  I specified the size since the internal RAM array would always be 8KB long.  Just a type safety thing, unless Rust is like C where C ignores array sizes in parameters?  Is it more efficient to use &[u8]?

Comment: @DanB91, it's just that the function accepts a slice it can work with arbitrary slices. For example, you could pass a slice made from a dynamically allocated `Vec`. But of course it depends on your particular use case, and type safety is always a good thing.

Comment: @DanB91: All the compiler knows is that the `[u8; 0x2000]` is being passed logically by value.  Which means you *might* modify it.  So it *has* to make a pre-emptive copy.  `&[u8; 0x2000]` explicitly tells it that you are *definitely* not going to modify the thing you're passed, so it doesn't need to make a copy.

Comment: @DK. What does taking ownership mean when the value is `Copy`?